# How to Rewrite Query String URL's in DNN

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke

i am using DNN (DotNetNuke) 6, I have urls like below,

```
http://localhost/Training/rpscategory.aspx?P=Oracle&Cat=Middleware
```

I want to rewrite above url like,

```
http://localhost/Training/Oracle/Middleware
```

and

```
http://localhost/Training/rpscategory.aspx?P=Oracle&Cat=Middleware&Course=Monitor-and-Performance
```

I want to rewrite above url like,

```
http://localhost/Training/Oracle/Middleware/Monitor-and-Performance
```

How to Achieve this

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented Rewrite Query String URL's in DNN by Using of [OpenUrlRewriter](https://openurlrewriter.codeplex.com/)

[Here is in detail..](https://openurlrewriter.codeplex.com/discussions/470404)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

UrlRouting Is More Useful And Easy to Understand See this Link. . It Will Definitely Help You

**Second Option**

UrlRewrite Option Is also Easy to use in IIS.IIS Provide This as a inbuilt Functionality.
You Have To just add the urlrewrite to iis which can downloaded from net and just add your url in IIS(Url Rewrite) It will make changes in Your WebConfig Automatically And Url Converted To User Friendly URl.

:-)